# Best Practices for handling JWT passing to other microservices

Tags: security, jwt, microservices, keycloak

We have a set of microservices where some are public facing for our UIs to call. The UI sends a JWT user token (obtained from the user login with keycloak) on requests to a microservice and that microservice may need to call another microservice. What is the best practice for sending a JWT from one microservice to the other. i.e.

1. microservices just pass through the original JWT user token to other microservices
2. microservices do a token exchange with the original JWT user for a JWT service token and inject the claims from the original into the new service token.
3. microservices obtain a JWT service token and sends that in the Authentication header and also sends the original JWT user token as some other header
4. microservices obtains a JWT service token and adds the original JWT user token as a claim in the new token.
5. some other mechanism not mentioned

Thanks.

Comment: What would be the benefits of 2,3,4 over 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> that microservice may need to call another microservice

Personally I would not allow such inter-microservices calls.
Instead, I would introduce a kind of "facade" (typically named an "API Gateway") in front of all micro-services, whose API will be invoked by the front-end.

Every coarse-grained service exposed by this facade is likely, behind the scenes, to chain N calls, potentially to different (fine-grained) micro-services.

This architecture allows two distinct security schemes

1. JWT tokens for **cross-layers** communication (ex: FrontEnd -> API GW; API GW -> micro-services)
2. BASIC auth account + mutual TLS when **backend -> backend** communication is needed

Nice article:
https://medium.com/ballerina-techblog/securing-microservices-with-jwt-a16b738b110f

My 2 cents,